# Gradle template with mongodb and rabbitmq services

Tags: mongodb, gradle, gitlab, rabbitmq

I use GitLab with Gradle https://gitlab.tech.orange/Orange-OpenSource/tbc/gradle.
I'd like to use services mongodb and rabbitmq like with :

```
services:
  - name: mongo:latest
    alias: mongo
  - name: rabbitmq:3-management
    alias: rabbitmq
```

but: gitlab-ci-gradle.yml don't see services from .gitlab-ci.yml

If I change directly in .gradle-base script (I've made a copy in my local dev) then it's ok.

Is it possible to have a generic gradle script ?
I'm not very good in gitlab script.

Thanks

Comment: On m'a aidé à trouver la réponse. Après avoir surchargé le template gradle initial, on m'a montré que je pouvais le surcharger depuis le `.gitlab-ci.yml` principal.

Ma solution pour avoir le docker mongo est maintenant la suivante, surcharge avec : 

```
.gradle-base:
  variables:
    MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: collectecrioi
  services:
    - name: mongo:latest
      alias: mongo
```

Le monde des dockers avec GitLab souvre à moi !

Comment: et l'uri de paramétrage pour Gitlab, on replace localhost par mongo comme ceci : uri: mongodb://mongo:27017